# Distinct sequences in a Fibonacci LFSR

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, lfsr

How many distinct sequences can a $128$-bit Fibonacci LFSR (considering $4$ taps set for the maximum period) generate? Will all $2^{128} - 1$ distinct seeds produce distinct sequences?

Also, let's say I discard the first $128$ bits and only consider the bits that occur after the MSB of the seed has come out of the output end (to avoid exposing the seed). How many distinct sequences will there be after this point? Won't there be only $2^4$ distinct sequences considering $2^4$ different permutations for the bits at the taps over all the distinct seeds?

Comment: Does "4 taps set for the maximum period" means that the feedback polynomial is chosen for maximum period, e.g. $x^{128}+x^7+x^2+x+1$ from [Jörg Arndt's Tables of mathematical data](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/), [Binary primitive polynomials with lowest-most possible set bits](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/lowbit-primpoly.txt)? If so, [this resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence) could help, in what could be homework.

Comment: The answer depends on what your professor considers distinct sequences. _All_ the nonzero sequences produced by your LFSR are cyclically shifted versions of one another, and _any_ 256 consecutive bits of the sequence are enough for anyone who knows the Berlekamp=Maeesy algorithm to determine the taps and the initial loading of the LFSR.

Comment: Yes, the primitive polynomial I've chosen for my implementation is $x^{128}+x^{127}+x^{126}+x^{121}+1$

Comment: Typo: that should have read Berlekamp-Massey algorithm